# Click a Button with Python Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, click, instagram

I have tried all the grabbing methods and I was not able to click on Not Now.
Xpath never worked, CSS selector..etc
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjGE3.png)

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: Hi Mira, welcome to SO, please do add the python code of what you have tried as well in the question, it will help us decode what exactly you might be doing wrong in those methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to click by text in the button, something like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(string(.),'Not Now']").click()
```

Comment: hello, Thank u so much, the issue was i didn't add sleep in between